# GraalVM compiled version of Spring Cloud Stream Kafka with Protobuf not able to serializer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder, s

I have a Spring Cloud Stream project with Kafka and Protobuf, the regular version works fine.

After compile with Graalvm it failed to producer Protobuf messages , the consumer works fine.

My project yaml is :

```
spring.cloud.stream:
    instanceCount: 1
    default-binder: kafka
    default:
        producer.useNativeEncoding: true
        consumer.useNativeEncoding: true
    kafka:
        binder:
            auto-create-topics: false
            brokers: ${spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers}
            consumer-properties:
                schema.registry.url: ${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}
                key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufDeserializer
                specific.protobuf.value.type: proto.dataFusion.VehicleInfo
                auto.offset.reset: latest
                auto.commit.enable: false
                ack.mode: manual_immediate
                isolation.level: read_committed
                max.poll.records: 150
                fetch.min.bytes: 1048576 # 1MB
                fetch.max.wait.ms: 1000
            producer-properties:
                schema.registry.url: ${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer
                enable.idempotence: false
```

I had a simular issue for consumer that was fixed after I set specific.protobuf.value.type property.

If value.serializer of the producer is set to String it works fine in the compiled version, but fail with Protobuf Serializer

But for the producer was no able to fix , I having the error :

```
2024-01-25T08:50:05.062-03:00 ERROR 8025 --- [sp-sc-cfc] [           main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService  : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Cannot initialize binder checking the topic (cfc_plates_to_check_muniz):
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:684) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionInfoForProducer(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:600) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:422) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:168) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:310) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:102) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:153) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:353) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:311) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:315) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:115) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:647) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:59) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:284) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:467) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[sp-sc-cfc:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:256) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:201) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:965) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[sp-sc-cfc:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1342) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1331) ~[sp-sc-cfc:3.2.0]
    at io.mobi7.sc.cfc.CFCServiceApplication.main(CFCServiceApplication.java:23) ~[sp-sc-cfc:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain partition information for the topic cfc_plates_to_check_muniz
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.lambda$getPartitionsForTopic$9(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:657) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[sp-sc-cfc:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209) ~[sp-sc-cfc:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:622) ~[sp-sc-cfc:4.1.0]
    ... 28 common frames omitted


2024-01-25T08:50:05.064-03:00 ERROR 8025 --- [sp-sc-cfc] [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'sp-sc-cfc.platesToCheck-out-0'., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=plate: "SIXXXXX"
, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=63e8b192-568c-c9b1-0867-52deb3eefce4, id=672f42d3-a458-0c59-b2e4-5841806869f2, sequenceSize=0, timestamp=1706183405063}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.doSend(AbstractMessageRouter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:210)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:501)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:356)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:285)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:249)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:151)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:378)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:349)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:329)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:302)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:206)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:481)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:467)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:419)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.thread.PlatformThreads.threadStartRoutine(PlatformThreads.java:775)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.posix.thread.PosixPlatformThreads.pthreadStartRoutine(PosixPlatformThreads.java:203)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=plate: "SIE7D4K"
, headers={sequenceNumber=1, correlationId=63e8b192-568c-c9b1-0867-52deb3eefce4, id=672f42d3-a458-0c59-b2e4-5841806869f2, sequenceSize=0, timestamp=1706183405063}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    ... 63 more
```

Here is the kafka and protobuf hints using :

```
 hints.reflection().registerType(NullContextNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(NullContextNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(TopicNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(TopicNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(Schema.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(Schema.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(SchemaString.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(SchemaString.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(SchemaReference.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(SchemaReference.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

 //Serializers
        hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufDeserializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufDeserializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufSerializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufSerializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

        //To create Protobuf
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.newBuilder().getCtype().getClass(), MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.newBuilder().getCtype().getClass(), MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.newBuilder().getJstype().getClass(), MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.newBuilder().getJstype().getClass(), MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.OptionRetention.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.OptionRetention.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.OptionTargetType.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FieldOptions.OptionTargetType.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.UninterpretedOption.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.UninterpretedOption.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.MessageOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.MessageOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.MessageOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.MessageOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.OptimizeMode.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.FileOptions.OptimizeMode.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumValueOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumValueOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumValueOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumValueOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumOptions.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);

        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(DescriptorProtos.EnumOptions.Builder.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
```

There is some others hits for the business ProtoBuf as well

I tried set a specific.protobuf.value.type to the produce.

I expect producer works in a compiled version like the interpreter one's

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because we are missing a native hint for `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer.` See the [hint](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/main/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/aot/KafkaRuntimeHints.java#L177) for `JsonSerializer` in Spring for Apache Kafka, for example. You can try adding a hint for `KafkaProtobufSerializer` in your application. If it works, add the hint to Oracle's [graalvm-reachability-metadata](https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/tree/master) repository by sending a PR there. Specifically, [this is where](https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata/blob/master/metadata/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/3.5.1/reflect-config.json#L143) the hint needs to get added. This way, not all applications don't have to add this custom hint in the applications.

Example code in : https://github.com/mmuniz75/scs-producer-graalvm

Update based on debugging the sample app: You are missing a native hint for `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.DefaultReferenceSubjectNameStrategy`.
You need the following hints:

```
hints.reflection().registerType(DefaultReferenceSubjectNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);
hints.reflection().registerType(DefaultReferenceSubjectNameStrategy.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
```

See this for more details:https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2896#issuecomment-1928598548

Comment: In fact for consume works I did a lot of hits but for producer still not works. I am updating the question with the hints

Comment: I already have it :      hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufSerializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_METHODS);
        hints.reflection().registerType(KafkaProtobufSerializer.class, MemberCategory.INVOKE_DECLARED_CONSTRUCTORS);

Comment: Looks like the issue is that Spring Cloud Stream is not able to figure out that this is a protobuf message and not a regular one : failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=plate: "SIEXXXX". It should be a protobuf message

Comment: Could you create a sample app and share it with us on GH? I will look further, then.

Comment: Here is an example code : https://github.com/mmuniz75/scs-producer-graalvm. Just need a Kafka running locally to run. This is a Supplier example with a pooler of 10s. The same issue happens with StreamBridge and Function

Comment: Could you add a README or instructions with commands to reproduce the issue? The gradle goals, java/graal versions needed etc.?

Comment: done https://github.com/mmuniz75/scs-producer-graalvm/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I am getting an error building the image. More details here: https://github.com/mmuniz75/scs-producer-graalvm/issues/1